# Email validation not working (android app)

Tags: android

I am working on an android application and I am facing some issues.
I am writing an activity for forgotten passwords in android studio (i'm using Firebase) and for some weird reason it doesn't work. You will get it when you see the code. I hope some of you geniuses can help me :)

[image]

Code:

```
public class Forgot extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mForgotEmail;
    Button mForgotButton;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot);

        mForgotButton = findViewById(R.id.recoveryBtn);
        mForgotEmail = findViewById(R.id.recoveryEmail);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        String forgotEmail = mForgotEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

        mForgotButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V){

                mForgotEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        if (forgotEmail.matches(emailPattern) && s.length() > 0)
                        {
                            mForgotButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            mForgotEmail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(forgotEmail);
                            Toast.makeText(Forgot.this, "Check your email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mForgotEmail.setError("Enter Valid Email Address");
                            mForgotEmail.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        // other stuffs
                    }
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        // other stuffs
                    }
                });






            }

        });


    }
}
```

Cheers
Kaspar

Comment: Can you provide the error? Some online code to test? You should be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, there are a few things that you might want to look into in this implementation, but first thing's first - currently in your `TextWatcher` you're evaluating towards `forgotEmail` and not the `s` variable that gets passed into the `afterTextChanged(...)` upon the text changing.

What that means is that `forgotEmail` will be set to an empty string at first (in `onCreate(...)`), and then that'll be what you're "validating" every time the contents of the `EditText` changes.

Suggestion:

Change `if (forgotEmail.matches(emailPattern) && s.length() > 0)` to `if (s.length() > 0 && s.toString().matches(emailPattern))` and you should get a more accurate "validation".

Two bonus thoughts:

1. [Email address validation is hard](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/). You probably should either go for the "bare minimum" with the existence of `<something>@<something else>` existing (basically `[^@]+@[^@]+`) or find a library that helps you out with the validation in regards of the actual standards surrounding email addresses.
2. You're currently adding one `TextWatcher` per click on the button. You could (should?) add the `TextWatcher` in `onCreate(...)`, but I reckon what you're trying to avoid is an error state upon the initial typing. You could just keep a boolean variable around so that you know if you've tried to submit the form once (=let loose the on-the-fly validation).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your code like below.

```
 mForgotButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V){

                mForgotEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        if (forgotEmail.matches(emailPattern) && s.length() > 0)
                        {
                            mForgotButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            mForgotEmail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            fAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(forgotEmail)
                              .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
 Toast.makeText(Forgot.this, "Check your email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
                                    }
                                    else{ //Do Something
                                        }
                                }
                            });;
                           
                          
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mForgotEmail.setError("Enter Valid Email Address");
                            mForgotEmail.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        // other stuffs
                    }
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        // other stuffs
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```